# Доп. инфо по ошибке APPCRASH clr.dll?

Tags: .net, windows, clr, reportviewer

После перевода декстопного .Net WinFoms приложения c .Net2.0 на .Net4.5 начал получать жалобы пользователей о том, что приложение периодически крашится. На скринах ошибка с примерно следующим содержанием:

```
Прекращена работа программы MyApp.exe
Сигнатура проблемы:
Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH
Имя приложения:MyApp.exe
Версия приложения 1.0
Имя модуля с ошибкой: clr.dll
Версия модуля с ошибкой 4.0.30319.18063
Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 526767сб
Код исключения с00000fd
Смещение исключения 00372f72
Версия ОС:6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Код языка: 1049
```

По логам которые пишет программа какой-либо ценной информации получить не удалось (данная ошибка не перехыватывается try/catch и Unhandled Exception, вся инфа из логов - методы выполнение которых началось перед падением ) Краши непостоянны. Методы при выполнении которых происходят краши разные. Объединяет их одно: все методы осуществляют работу с rdlc отчётами - используя методы установленного на пк ReportViewer'a 15-ой версии.

Сначала грешил на репорт - переустановил его и всё что с ним связано - безрезультатно. 
Потом вычитал что возможно проблема в .Net'e. Переустановил 4,5. Накатил обновы которые, исходя из найденных мною тем с аналогичными проблемами, могут её исправить - безрезультатно. Обновление .Net'a до 4.6.2 так же проблему не решило.

Удалённая отладка - не вариант. Локально проблема не воспроизводится. Но разобраться как-то нужно.

Соответственно хотелось бы получить больше информации (дампы, логи, ect) о данной ошибке, это возможно?

Comment: Из приведенных данных следует, что это переполнение стека. Возможно, у вас там слишком глубокая вложенность циклов или рекурсия. Также, упало в clr.dll 2013 года или более ранней, возможно причина тут. Еще можно запросить с этой машины оную dll и посмотреть где именно упало, но это будет код рантайма и сомневаюсь в полезности сего действия.

Comment: Вложенных циклов и рекурсий в моём коде нет. Теоретически может быть в подключаемых либах ReportViewer'a но тогда я бы эту ошибку мог воспроизвести локально при печати такого же отчёта, но у меня всё ок, да и у пользователей повтор печати того же самого проходит без ошибок.

Comment: Ну в приведенных данных написано именно то, что я уже написал.

Comment: Да, что именно означает большая часть инфы по ошибке я узнал. Это только добавило вопросов. 
А как имея clr.dll посмотреть где именно упало? Если там IL код то если ничего иного не нарою, можно будет и его почитать. Asm пожалуй не сдюжу...

Comment: В clr.dll код нативный. 00372f72 - вероятно и есть RVA относительно Imagebase, где оно все и упало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии .Net 4.0 CLR по умолчанию не даёт возможности перехвата исключений связанных с поврежденным состоянием (Corrupted State Exceptions) - CSE. 
( данное решение было принято т.к. нет никаких доступных разработчику вариантов восстановления/исправления состояния кроме как перезапуск приложения )

При переходе с Net <4 на Net4+ старый код try{}catch{} работавший в т.ч. с CSE перестаёт их отлавливать. 
Для исправления этой ситуации есть два варианта:

1) Прописать в app.config

```
<runtime> <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true"/> </runtime>
```

-- меняет поведение "по умолчанию" для CSE позволяя перехватывать такие исключения в try{}catch{} во всём приложении.

2) Добавить к методу где возможны подобные ошибки атрибут `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]`

-- Позволит перехватить CSE в методе который помечен данным атрибутом. Надо учитывать тот факт, что если требуется перехват при вложенных вызовах на более высоком уровне ( ошибка происходит в методе m3 который вызывается m2 который вызывается m1, перехватчик установлен в m1 ) данным атрибутом необходимо пометить всю цепочку.

Оба варианта в моём случае позволили мне получить более детальные сведения о ошибке, локализовать первопричину и составить рекомендации по исправлению для пользователей.

PS: При перехвате CSE я лично не рекомендую обрабатывать это исключение с продолжением работы программы. Максимум - запись деталей в лог, осмысленное сообщение об ошибке пользователю, освобождение неуправляемых ресурсов